# Android Standalone Content Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to create an Android application that just provides a standalone content provider? So far I have implemented a class that implements ContentProvider and have added it to my AndroidManifest.xml. When I build I don't get any errors but I don't see that an .apk has been generated and if I try to launch the application from Android Studio I get "Default Activity not found".

Comment: "if I try to launch the application from Android Studio I get "Default Activity not found"" -- well, that is because you do not have an activity, let alone a launcher one. Change your run configuration to just install the APK.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks for the feedback. Haha, I understand why I was getting that particular message, I guess I should have been more clear why I was mentioning it. Anyways, from your comment though it sounds like it is possible to have an .apk that only contains a standalone Content Provider. Correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. It definitely works for pre-installed apps. For ordinary apps, I do not know. Apps, when installed, go into a "stopped state". In that state, manifest-registered receivers do not work. The app moves out of the "stopped state" when an explicit `Intent` is used to start one of the app's components, and that usually means that the user tapped on the home screen launcher icon. Apps lacking such an activity cannot move out of the stopped state that way. I do not know if providers are blocked this way, or if an app talks to the provider if it moves the app out of the stopped state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else runs across this post... yes, it is possible to have an application that only provides a content provider.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to 'edit configurations' from the drop-down next to the run button and selected device drop-down on the toolbar
2. Click your project module name ('app' for example)
3. Under the 'General' tab, you'll find a set of 'Launch Options'; change the 'Launch:' setting from 'Default Activity' to 'Nothing'
4. Not necessary, but a good idea would be to build>clean and build>rebuild
5. Try running the project from the toolbar, or generate and install an APK